# How to document.write when specific option selected from drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to carry out a document.write when a specific option is selected from the drop-down menu.

Here's what I have so far:

**HTML**

```
<select name="active" class="button_select" id="active" style="width:150px" >
<option id="on" value="on">Online</option>
<option id="off" value="" <?php if($rows['active']=='') { echo 'selected'; } elseif ($rows['active']=='on' && $rows['images'] == 0) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Offline</option>
<option id="arch" value="arch" <?php if($rows['active']=='arch') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Archived</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>        
$("#active").change(function(){
var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");

switch (id){
case "on":
document.write('<a href="select.php"><img src="../images/icons/coquette/48x48/accept.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>');
break;
}
});             
</script>
```

I've placed the Javascript above the HTML - currently when the `on` option is selected nothing appears where the `accept.png` should appear.

Can anybody suggest a solution?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/yqx7thp6/5/)

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar it will not work if you will remove `onLoad`, which is not presented in question: [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yqx7thp6/6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Wrap your code with `$(document).ready`.
- You can use `.replaceWith()` instead of `document.write` (just to mention).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc38uz6p/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#active").change(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
        switch(id)
        {
            case "on":
                $(this).replaceWith('<a href="select.php"><img src="../images/icons/coquette/48x48/accept.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

**Update** with handling selected option during `$(document).ready`:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc38uz6p/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#active").change(function()
    {
        handleSelected($(this));
    });

    handleSelected($('#active'));

    function handleSelected(jElement)
    {
        var id = jElement.find("option:selected").attr("id");
        switch(id)
        {
            case "on":
                $("div.wrapper").replaceWith('<a href="select.php"><img src="../images/icons/coquette/48x48/accept.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>');
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - see my updated code above. I'm still having problems with making it work.

Comment: I've have it working now, thanks. Is it possible to extend this function so that it also replaces the `<div>` with the same if the option is already selected on page load. At the moment the image only shows onChange to the option `on`. However, if the option is already selected on page load the image is blank. How would this be done?

Comment: @aphextwix you can put this logic into separate function and call this function not only in `change` handler, but also in `ready` handler, like in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc38uz6p/3/).

Comment: That's now working as expected. Would you mind updating your answer to reflect the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code this way:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#active").change(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
        switch(id)
        {
            case "on":
                $("body").append('<a href="select.php"><img src="../images/icons/coquette/48x48/accept.png" alt="" border="0" /></a>');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/g9bm7mko/